# Replace and save remaining string in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove predefined parts of the strings in the following table and save the values in an array. For some reason I get an error stating that I'm outside of the index. The lengths of the strings in the table can vary.

```
Sub New_1()

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim Endings As Variant
k = 0
    
Endings = Array("/A", "/BB", "/CCC", "/DDDD", "/EEEEE")

Dim ArrayValues() As Variant

With Worksheets("table1")

    Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ReDim ArrayValues(lastRow)
        
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    
        For j = 0 To UBound(Endings)
        
            ArrayValues(k) = Replace(.Range("A" & i), Endings(j), "")
            k = k + 1
        
        Next j
        
    Next i
    
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what's causing the error here, it's his k=k+1 being inside the j iteration and for what I can see in my vba, it starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: Your `for j ...` loop is storing four items in sequential elements of ArrayValue for each entry on your worksheet.  You probably only want to store a single value.

Comment: You should place `k = k + 1` after the loop ending with `Next j`. I suppose that you need a single value obtained by replacing of all `Endings` array elements. Is that supposition correct?

Comment: Why do you iterate backwards? Then, at the code end you should use `Redim Preserve ArrayValues(k -1)`. To avoid having a last empty element. Depending on what you intend doing with the array, it may stay there, but usually is good to have an array without empty elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting out of bounds because your ArrValues is filled up after not even 3 iterations of your "i" since you're adding up your k every j iterations

If you want an array of the cleaned up cells do this instead:

```
Sub New_1()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim Endings As Variant
    Dim ArrayValues() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
        
    Endings = Array("/A", "/BB", "/CCC", "/DDDD", "/EEEEE")
    
    With Worksheets("Blad6")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim ArrayValues(1 To lastRow) 'Then you don't have an empty ArrayValues(0)
            
        For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            For j = 0 To UBound(Endings)
                If j = 0 Then
                    ArrayValues(i) = Replace(.Range("A" & i), Endings(j), "")
                Else
                    ArrayValues(i) = Replace(ArrayValues(i), Endings(j), "")
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        'Use Array here
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to create an array in which everything after the `/` is removed, this might be simpler, using the `Split` function; and also faster by storing the data to be split in a VBA array, in iterating through that array instead of the worksheet cells.

```
Option Explicit
Sub New_1()

'in VBA, Long is marginally more efficient than Integer
  Dim k As Long, v As Variant
  Dim dataArr As Variant
  Dim ArrayValues() As Variant

With Worksheets("SHEET7")

'faster to loop through VBA array than worksheet cells
'Note that this will be a 2D array with dimensions starting at 1, not 0
    dataArr = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'This might be simpler
ReDim ArrayValues(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1))
k = 0
For Each v In dataArr
    k = k + 1
    ArrayValues(k) = Split(v, "/")(0)
Next v
    
End Sub
```